# Set images randomly in the grid in Android

Tags: android, gridview, random

I am using a version of the "Grid View" example from the Android Developers site:  http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html  And I would like to display images in reach grid randomly and the image position will change in each click.  Can someone please give an example of how this might be accomplished (i.e. what needs to be edited)?  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! According to your other questions: please read [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). You provided in none of your questions what you have tried. See also [this site](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a custom [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html), where you need to check which items are visible and select then a random image which is not visible. Bute note that a total random list will confuse your users. Better sort your images by random and visualizate them same in one instance.

Comment: Thanks for helping me.Can you please refer any sample coding for this.

Comment: I don't like to do your work. But if you provide your actual code (or better what you have tried) I will happy to help you. By the way this video here is very helpful: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: Thanks for helping.I need only the reference,I will try myself.Thanks onceagain